# Display text once within while loop on the first loop

Tags: php, while-loop

```
<?php

$i = 0;

while(conditionals...) {

if($i == 0)
  print "<p>Show this once</p>";

print "<p>display everytime</p>";
$i++;
}
?>
```

Would this only show "Show this once" the first time and only that time, and show the "display everytime" as long as the while loop goes thru?

Comment: why not just run it yourself and see if it works?

Comment: I was asking this question for another person & sent them the URL to view the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, indeed.

You can also combine the if and the increment, so you won't forget to increment:

```
if (!$i++) echo "Show once.";
```

Answer (score 6):

Rather than incrementing it every time the loop runs and wasting useless resource, what you can do is, if the value is 0 for the first time, then print the statement and make the value of the variable as non-zero. Just like a flag. Condition, you are not changing the value of the variable in between the loop somewhere. Something like this:

```
<?php

   $i = 0;

   while(conditionals...) {

      if($i == 0){
        print "<p>Show this once</p>";
        $i=1;
      }

      print "<p>display everytime</p>";
   }
?>
```

Comment: Adding a non-zero value inside the loop worked for me!! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as nothing in the loop sets $i back to 0

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will, unless the conditions are false from the start or $i was set to 0 inside the loop