# display multiple data only once

Tags: php, loops, csv, foreach

I'm creating a table based upon an imported .csv file.

This works fine however I want to spit out the company name once.

So this is the **csv**:

```
company,value  
company1, 231  
company1, 432  
company1, 876
```

If I `foreach` the data into a table I want to display the `companyname` once.

```
echo'<table><tr><td>Companyname</td><td>Value</td>';
foreach ($data as $gegevens){
    $companyname = $gegevens['Companyname'];
    $value = $gegevens['Value'];
    echo '<tr><td>'.$companyname.'</td><td>'.$value.'</td></tr> ';

}   
echo'</table>';
```

This is what I want to have as output:
[Companyname] [Value]
[company 1  ]       [231]
[                    ]       [432]
[                   ]       [876]

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Could you show us what the desired output is supposed to look like?

Comment: @domdom Please see my update

Comment: Then use a boolean flag that you trigger after the first loop. See [Bibhudatta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44823171/3316645). Although I'd advice to name it something more meaningful than just `$flag`. Also you most likely want to check out [`rowspan`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706468/how-to-make-a-td-on-more-than-one-row).

Comment: Also, here is [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831501/display-text-once-within-while-loop-on-the-first-loop) that is using the loop's counter instead of `if` - which is probably not what you want, seeing that you don't have a counter, but still...

Comment: And: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22482149/3316645) on this possible duplicate: [How do I execute a specific code block for only the first iteration of a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481925/how-do-i-execute-a-specific-code-block-for-only-the-first-iteration-of-a-loop)

Comment: @Interactive You want to have new `<tr>` for each row regardless of company?  Do you not want line breaks between each value to keep things in the same cell?  Do you want the `company1` cell to span multiple rows?  It seems sloppy to me to write new rows each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See OP's comment on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44823171/3316645):

> Haha almost..... This must be my fault for not explaining correct. There are (off course) multiple companies. So create a if statement or something?

Therefore, I would suggest something like this:

```
$data = array(
    array('Companyname' => 'FBI', 'Value' => '1'),
    array('Companyname' => 'CIA', 'Value' => '2'),
    array('Companyname' => 'CIA', 'Value' => '3'),
    array('Companyname' => 'CIA', 'Value' => '4'),
    array('Companyname' => 'NSA', 'Value' => '5'),
    array('Companyname' => 'NSA', 'Value' => '6'),
);

$last_company = ""; // What was the last company we printed?

echo'<table><tr><td>Companyname</td><td>Value</td>';
foreach ($data as $gegevens){
    $companyname = $gegevens['Companyname'];
    $value = $gegevens['Value'];
    if ($companyname == $last_company) {
        echo '<tr><td></td><td>'.$value.'</td></tr>';
    } else {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$companyname.'</td><td>'.$value.'</td></tr>';
        $last_company = $companyname;
    }
}
echo'</table>';
```

This generates the following output (when viewed with a browser):

```
Companyname Value
FBI         1
CIA         2
            3
            4
NSA         5
            6
```

Comment: @pAsh absolutely correct. However, seeing how this is tabular data, I would assume it is either sorted or printing the company name again would even be desired (otherwise, how could you tell what company the value belongs to? You would think it belongs to the last one you printed). Worst case, we can always sort the array first. *In other words*: what you describe is a feature rather than a bug.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this using flag variable.

```
   $flag=True;
    echo'<table><tr><td>Companyname</td><td>Value</td>';
    foreach ($data as $gegevens){
        $companyname = $gegevens['Companyname'];
        $value = $gegevens['Value'];
    if($flag){
    $flag=false;
        echo '<tr><td>'.$companyname.'</td><td>'.$value.'</td></tr> ';
    }else{
        echo '<tr><td> </td><td>'.$value.'</td></tr> ';
    }
    }   
    echo'</table>';
```

I thing it will solve your issue.

Comment: I would've used a ternary to make it less verbose, but that's a question of style. However, in the name of best practices, I would recommend to name the flag something more meaningful than just `flag`. PS: s/thing/think

Comment: I see where you are going with this but it doesn't work. I only shows the else values. So it's like the first loop is ignored! Set the first `$flag` to true

Comment: Just please check it once again i modified it.

Comment: I just missed $flag=True; first time.

Comment: Haha almost..... This must be my fault for not explaining correct. There are (off course) multiple companies. So create a if statement or something?

Comment: Interactive, you really should edit your question to clarify that (multiple companies), as this calls for different answers as your original question!

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php 
 $data = array(

    array('Companyname' => 'Company', 'Value' => '10'),
    array('Companyname' => 'Company1', 'Value' => '10'),
    array('Companyname' => 'Company1', 'Value' => '10'),
    array('Companyname' => 'Company2', 'Value' => '10'),
 ); 

 $newdata = array();

 foreach ($data as $gegevens){
    $newdata[$gegevens['Companyname']][] = $gegevens['Value']; 
 }

 echo'<table><tr><td>Companyname</td><td>Value</td>';
 foreach($newdata as $company => $values) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$companyname.'</td><td>'.implode('<br>' ,$values).'</td></tr> ';
}
echo'</table>';
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rows = array();
foreach($data as $gegevens) {
    $companyname = $gegevens['Companyname'];
    $value = $gegevens['Value'];
    echo '<tr><td>'.$companyname.'</td><td>'.$value.'</td></tr> ';
    if(isset($rows[$companyname])) {
        $rows[$companyname] .= '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>'.$value.'</td></tr> ';
    } else {
        $rows[$companyname] =  '<tr><td>'.$companyname.'</td><td>'.$value.'</td></tr> ';
    }
}
echo'<table><tr><td>Companyname</td><td>Value</td>';
echo implode("",$rows);
```